# GitLab installation failing on RHEL 7

Tags: redhat, git, gitlab

I'm trying to install GitLab 7.0 on RHEL 7 (using the CentOS omnibus package), but the installation keeps failing at the step below. Any suggestions as to how to get the installation to complete successfully?

```
  * execute[initctl status gitlab-runsvdir] action run
================================================================================
Error executing action `run` on resource 'execute[initctl status gitlab-runsvdir]'
================================================================================


Errno::ENOENT
-------------
No such file or directory - initctl


Resource Declaration:
---------------------
# In /opt/gitlab/embedded/cookbooks/runit/recipes/upstart.rb

 29: execute "initctl status gitlab-runsvdir" do
 30:   retries 30
 31: end
 32:



Compiled Resource:
------------------
# Declared in /opt/gitlab/embedded/cookbooks/runit/recipes/upstart.rb:29:in `from_file'

execute("initctl status gitlab-runsvdir") do
  action "run"
  retries 0
  retry_delay 2
  guard_interpreter :default
  command "initctl status gitlab-runsvdir"
  backup 5
  returns 0
  cookbook_name :runit
  recipe_name "upstart"
end




Running handlers:
[2014-07-07T12:23:16-04:00] ERROR: Running exception handlers
Running handlers complete

[2014-07-07T12:23:16-04:00] ERROR: Exception handlers complete
[2014-07-07T12:23:16-04:00] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to /opt/gitlab/embedded/cookbooks/cache/chef-stacktrace.out
Chef Client failed. 2 resources updated in 62.2579311 seconds
[2014-07-07T12:23:16-04:00] ERROR: execute[initctl status gitlab-runsvdir] (runit::upstart line 29) had an error: Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory - initctl
[2014-07-07T12:23:16-04:00] FATAL: Chef::Exceptions::ChildConvergeError: Chef run process exited unsuccessfully (exit code 1)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to contact the gitlab developers and obtain an updated package which is compatible with EL7. This is failing because it can't find various bits of upstart which is only present in EL6.

Comment: I was afraid that would be the answer. Alright, I'll go from there then. Thank you!

Comment: You might also _yell at them_ for using the Upstart variant of the commands in the first place, instead of the forward-compatible Red Hat commands.

Comment: The download is technically for CentOS 6, which may explain the difference. It claims to be compatible with RHEL 6 as well, which is why I downloaded it. I was just hoping it would work with RHEL 7, but that's not the case.